# i have extracted some values using regex in beanshell postprocessor now i have to pick a random value and store it into a varaible?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;


String responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
// log.info("the response data is : " + responseData);

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<option value=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)</option>");
// log.info("pattern is : " + pattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(responseData);
// log.info("matcher is :" + matcher);

while(matcher.find())
{
    log.info("the cities are : " + matcher.group(1));
    String extractedCity = matcher.group(1);
    log.info("the extracted city is : " + extractedCity);
    vars.put("Depart_city" , extractedCity);
}[log level output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANKbl.png)
```

i am able to extract the data but i am unable to pick a random value from the result and store it into a jmeter variaable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're overwriting the value on each match, you should rather store them into a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and then get the random item from the list, something like:

   ```
   import java.util.Random;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import org.apache.commons.lang.math.RandomUtils;


   String responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
   // log.info("the response data is : " + responseData);

   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<option value=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)</option>");
   // log.info("pattern is : " + pattern);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(responseData);
   // log.info("matcher is :" + matcher);
   List cities = new ArrayList();
   while(matcher.find())
   {
       log.info("the cities are : " + matcher.group(1));
       String extractedCity = matcher.group(1);
       log.info("the extracted city is : " + extractedCity);
       cities.add(extractedCity);
   }
   vars.put("Depart_city", cities.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(cities.size())));
   ```
2. Using Beanshell is some form of a performance ant-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
3. [Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8592047), you could rather go for [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library
4. And last but not the least, you don't need any scripting at all, you could get the random city from the response into a JMeter Variable using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor):

   [image]

Comment: the code is picking the value in sequential order but i want to pick the value in a random manner... sorry for the inconvenience i am new to jmeter so please help me.... @Ivan G